Why doesn't the infobox change when I first click left after clicking right a few times? (The same problem occurs when going from left to right)
Expected Result
When you click the prevBtn for the first time:
The carousel should rotate to show the previous fruit.
The corresponding background should change.
The info box should update to show information related to the new active fruit.
Actual Result
When you click the prevBtn for the first time:
The carousel rotates, but the info box does not update to reflect the new fruit's information.
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel {
    height: 100vh;
}

.img-box {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1000px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 1600px;
    height: 1600px;
}

.img-box .img-list {
    height: inherit;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.info-slider {
    transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
}

.img-list .img-slider {
    height: inherit;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    transition: .5s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
}

.img-slider .img-item {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    transform: rotate(calc(360deg / 4 * var(--i)));
    transform-origin: 800px;
}

.img-item img {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1));
}

.img-item.fruit img {
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-30%);
    scale: 0;
    transition: .5s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
    animation: float-fruit 4s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.img-item.fruit.active img {
    scale: 1;
    transition-delay: .1s;
}

@keyframes float-fruit {
    0% {
        translate: 0;
    }

    50% {
        translate: -20px;
    }

    100% {
        translate: 0;
    }
}

.info-box {
    position: absolute;
    right: 8%;
    bottom: 5%;
    width: 350px;
    height: 150px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.info-box .info-slider {
    transition: .5s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
}

.info-slider .info-item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
    height: 150px;
}

.info-item h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.navigation {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 90%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    z-index: 100;
}

.navigation span {
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 55px;
    color: #fff;
}

.large-text {
    position: absolute;
    left: 15%;
    top: 60%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    height: 700px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

.large-text h2 {
    font-size: 160px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    text-orientation: upright;
    letter-spacing: 30px;
    user-select: none;
}

.bg-box .bg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
}

.bg-box .bg.active {
    opacity: 1;
}

.bg-box .bg::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
    border-radius: 50%;
    filter: blur(200px);
} 

.bg-box .bg:nth-child(1) {
    background: #55a0f0;
}

.bg-box .bg:nth-child(2) {
    background: #df9e7d;
}

.bg-box .bg:nth-child(3) {
    background: #6cc680;
}

.bg-box .bg:nth-child(4) {
    background: #e9a5b2;
}

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Slider Carousel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="carousel">

        <div class="bg-box">
            <div class="bg active"></div>
            <div class="bg"></div>
            <div class="bg"></div>
            <div class="bg"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="img-box">
            <div class="img-list">
                <div class="img-slider">
                    <div class="img-item fruit active" style="--i:0;">
                        <img src="images/fruit1.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-item fruit" style="--i:1;">
                        <img src="images/fruit2.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-item fruit" style="--i:2;">
                        <img src="images/fruit3.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-item fruit" style="--i:3;">
                        <img src="images/fruit4.png">
                    </div>

                    <div class="img-item" style="--i:0;">
                        <img src="images/can1.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-item" style="--i:1;">
                        <img src="images/can2.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-item" style="--i:2;">
                        <img src="images/can3.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-item" style="--i:3;">
                        <img src="images/can4.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="info-box">
            <div class="info-slider">
                <div class="info-item">
                    <h2>Blueberry</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Exercitationem molestias eligendi sunt nesciunt unde beatae asperiores dolorum quia praesentium a repudiandae, ad repellat pariatur nisi.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="info-item">
                    <h2>Orange</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Exercitationem molestias eligendi sunt nesciunt unde beatae asperiores dolorum quia praesentium a repudiandae, ad repellat pariatur nisi.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="info-item">
                    <h2>Green Apple</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Exercitationem molestias eligendi sunt nesciunt unde beatae asperiores dolorum quia praesentium a repudiandae, ad repellat pariatur nisi.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="info-item">
                    <h2>Strawberry</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Exercitationem molestias eligendi sunt nesciunt unde beatae asperiores dolorum quia praesentium a repudiandae, ad repellat pariatur nisi.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="large-text">
            <h2>埃赖克</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="navigation">
            <span class="prev-btn">
                <i class='bx bx-chevron-left' ></i>
            </span>
            <span class="next-btn">
                <i class='bx bx-chevron-right' ></i>
            </span>
        </div>

    </div>


    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

const imgSlider = document.querySelector('.img-slider');
const imgFruits = document.querySelectorAll('.img-item.fruit');
const infoBox = document.querySelector('.info-box');
const infoSlider = document.querySelector('.info-slider');
const bgs = document.querySelectorAll('.bg');

const nextBtn = document.querySelector('.next-btn');
const prevBtn = document.querySelector('.prev-btn');

let indexSlider = 0;
let index = 0;
let direction;

function initialize() {
    imgFruits[0].classList.add('active');
    bgs[0].classList.add('active');
    updateInfo(0); // Başlangıçta bilgi kutusunu ayarlayın
}

function updateInfo(index) {
    const activeInfo = infoSlider.querySelector('.info-item.active');
    if (activeInfo) activeInfo.classList.remove('active');
    infoSlider.children[index].classList.add('active');
}

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    indexSlider++;
    imgSlider.style.transform = `rotate(${indexSlider * -90}deg)`;

    index++;
    if (index > imgFruits.length - 1) {
        index = 0;
    }

    updateActiveItems(1);
    updateInfo(index); 
});

prevBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    indexSlider--;
    imgSlider.style.transform = `rotate(${indexSlider * -90}deg)`;

    index--;
    if (index < 0) {
        index = imgFruits.length - 1;
    }

    updateActiveItems(-1);
    
    updateInfo(index);
});

function updateActiveItems(direction) {
    document.querySelector('.fruit.active').classList.remove('active');
    imgFruits[index].classList.add('active');

    document.querySelector('.bg.active').classList.remove('active');
    bgs[index].classList.add('active');

    infoSlider.style.transition = 'none';
    infoSlider.style.transform = 'translateY(0)';

    if (direction === 1) {
        infoSlider.appendChild(infoSlider.firstElementChild);
    } else {
        infoSlider.prepend(infoSlider.lastElementChild);
    }

    infoSlider.offsetHeight; // Force reflow
    infoSlider.style.transition = 'cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1)';
    infoSlider.style.transform = direction === 1 ? 'translateY(-25%)' : 'translateY(25%)';

    infoBox.style.justifyContent = direction === 1 ? 'flex-start' : 'flex-end';
}

infoSlider.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
    infoSlider.style.transition = 'none';
    infoSlider.style.transform = 'translateY(0)';

    setTimeout(() => {
        infoSlider.style.transition = 'cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1)';
    }, 0);
});

initialize();


I just want a circle of changing fruit names. forward and backward. Arranging queque is the main problem. I also tried this:
nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {

    indexSlider++;
    imgSlider.style.transform = rotate(${indexSlider * -90}deg);

    index++;
    if (index > imgFruits.length - 1) {
        index = 0;
    }

    document.querySelector('.fruit.active').classList.remove('active');
    imgFruits[index].classList.add('active');

    document.querySelector('.bg.active').classList.remove('active');
    bgs[index].classList.add('active');

    if (direction == 1) {
        infoSlider.prepend(infoSlider.lastElementChild);
    }
    
    direction = -1;

    infoBox.style.justifyContent = 'flex-start';
    infoSlider.style.transform = 'translateY(-25%)';

});

prevBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {

    indexSlider--;
    imgSlider.style.transform = rotate(${indexSlider * -90}deg);

    index--;
    if (index < 0){
        index = imgFruits.length - 1;
    }

    document.querySelector('.fruit.active').classList.remove('active');
    imgFruits[index].classList.add('active');

    document.querySelector('.bg.active').classList.remove('active');
    bgs[index].classList.add('active');

    if (direction == -1) {
        infoSlider.appendChild(infoSlider.firstElementChild);
    }
    
    direction = 1;

    infoBox.style.justifyContent = 'flex-end';
    infoSlider.style.transform = 'translateY(25%)';

});

infoSlider.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {

    if (direction == -1) {
        infoSlider.appendChild(infoSlider.firstElementChild);
    }
    else if (direction == 1) {
        infoSlider.prepend(infoSlider.lastElementChild);
    }

    infoSlider.style.transition = 'none';
    infoSlider.style.transform = 'translateY(0)';

    setTimeout(() => {
        infoSlider.style.transition = 'cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1)';
    })

})

This one starts good but stops at 3rd fruit and previous button doesn't work properly. I tried these kind of solutions but I did not like these style and animation. My current style in css is good but js part doesn't work well.

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre], including relevant html. How does infoData relate to the rest of the script?

It's hard to suggest a solution without the full context. What are nextBtn, prevBtn, initialize()? How does infoData relate to the rest of the script?

Should I add the css code too?

If the problem includes css, yes.

Please be specific about "doesn't work properly". What's the expected result vs actual result? Are there any errors in your dev console? For one thing, I'm seeing template literal notation ${variable}, but without the backticks, which may be causing issues.

Where are .prev-btn and .next-btn?

You can see all of the codes.

Could it be that the prev and next buttons are overlapped by other text?

No, buttons are staying at up of the text

What steps have you taken to debug this? Are there any errors in the dev console?Are the variables in your callback functions what you expect?
